# MySQL query optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization, join

I am having join query that seems fetching slowly. How can I optimize it, or it is 
reasonable?

> time to execute
>   29 total, Query took 1.6956 sec

## mysql query

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
  t2.AuctionID ,t2.product_name ,t3.user_name ,t1.date_time ,t1.owned_price
  ,t2.specific_product_id
FROM table_user_ownned_auction AS t1 
INNER JOIN table_product AS t2 ON t1.specific_product_id=t2.specific_product_id
INNER JOIN table_user_information AS t3 ON t3.user_id=t1.user_id  
ORDER BY ownned_id DESC
```

Here's the explain output

[image: Explain output]

Comment: can you tell us which columns are indexed?  and how big the tables are?

Comment: Do you need `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`, since there's no specified `LIMIT`?

Comment: @alec : I see no reason for it without the `LIMIT`

Comment: @stevels : t1 :7 columns,t2:35 columns,t3:22 columns ... what you mean by indexed column, here specific_product_id,user_id,ownned_id are primary and auto increment

Comment: @alec : i am using jquery data table.here with out  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS function pagination will not work.is there any problem with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the explain output, your problem is in
[image: Explain output]

The second line: The join with table `t1`.
Put an index on `t1.specific_product_id` and `t2.specific_product_id`.

the first line has one 3 rows in it, `using filesort` on that is actually faster than using the index because it saves on I/O-time.

The following code will add an index to `t2.specific_product_id`.

```
ALTER TABLE table_product ADD INDEX spi(specific_product_id);
```

Because you only have 29 rows of output, using the index should speed up your query to instantaneous.

Comment: how to add index  to  specific_product_id field .it's already primary_key. i don't know anything about index .untill know.help me !

Comment: @gowri, updated the answer to include the statement to add an index.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand the performance issues of a query, just use the EXPLAIN keyword in front of your query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
  ,t2.AuctionID ,t2.product_name ,t3.user_name ,t1.date_time ,t1.owned_price
  ,t2.specific_product_id
FROM table_user_ownned_auction AS t1 inner
JOIN table_product AS t2 ON t1.specific_product_id=t2.specific_product_id
INNER JOIN table_user_information AS t3 ON t3.user_id=t1.user_id  
ORDER BY ownned_id DESC
```

It will tell you important information about your query. The most important columns are "key" and "Extra".

If "key" is NULL you need an index. Mostly for columns that are used in `WHERE` or `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY` statements. "Extra" tells you about resource-consuming (CPU or Memory) operations.

So, add an index on the "ownned_id" (which i presume should be "owned_id") and explain it again. Then look at the performance gain.

If you have problems, I can help you better if you paste the EXPLAIN output.

Comment: could you explain .. here is explain output http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ceczlte5

Comment: how can i index ownned_id column its already primary_key and auto increment

Comment: Primary means it is indexed and also unique. So there is no need to add another index for it. For an explanation of your EXPLAIN output look at Johan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your explain table ,type are all which is very bad if you have more than 10 000 row in your table .I  Strongly advise to index this column in your table

1. t1.specific_product_id
2. t2.specific_product_id
3. t3.user_id
4. t1.user_id

If should your table reach 10 000 row , you should be be able to see perfomance boost. For more information please this video from 00:00 to 02:04 minutes , As you can in the below video , before indexing the query have to search more than 90000 row of data and after index it will search less than 5 row of data hope it will help.

https://www.youtube.com/edit?o=U&video_id=ojyEcNMAj8k